# Can't link libpqxx in g++

Tags: c++, postgresql, linker-errors, libpq, libpqxx

MacOS 12.2.2, clang 13.0.0, XCode developer tools are installed. libpqxx was installed with the homebrew and can be found with include, but the linker cannot find the library.

```
> g++ main.cpp -lpq -lpqxx -I/opt/homebrew/include -std=c++2a
ld: library not found for -lpq
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here is main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pqxx/pqxx>

using namespace std;
using namespace pqxx;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   try {
      connection C("dbname = testdb user = pgtest password = pgtest \
      hostaddr = 127.0.0.1 port = 5432");
      if (C.is_open()) {
         cout << "Opened database successfully: " << C.dbname() << endl;
      } else {
         cout << "Can't open database" << endl;
         return 1;
      }
      C.close ();
   } catch (const std::exception &e) {
      cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
      return 1;
   }
}
```

Comment: You gave your compiler the include path but did not tell it the folder location for the libraries.

Comment: Isn't folder "pqxx" the library? On debian it could find the stuff itself.

Comment: `libpq` has to be on the library path as well.